# problem executing a python cgi script in apache webserver

Tags: python, apache, scripting, cgi

I have searched and read other posts with similar problems. I fixed the shebang line in the .py file and made sure that httpd.conf has correct config. Unfortunately, nothing has resolved my problem and I still get the dreaded errors -

```
[Mon Jun 01 10:37:02.994516 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 19596:tid 1196] (OS 1920)The file cannot be accessed by the system.  : [client ::1:50159] couldn't create child process: 721920: upload_file.py
[Mon Jun 01 10:37:02.994516 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 19596:tid 1196] (OS 1920)The file cannot be accessed by the system.  : [client ::1:50159] AH01223: couldn't spawn child process: C:/Users/raj_d/webroot/tsp_quick/cgi-bin/upload_file.py
```

The Python script -

```
#!"C:\Users\raj_d\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
import cgi, os
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
# Get filename here.
fileitem = form['filename']
# Test if the file was uploaded
if fileitem.filename:
   # strip leading path from file name to avoid
   # directory traversal attacks
   fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
   open('/tmp/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())
   message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'
else:
   message = 'No file was uploaded'
print """\
Content-Type: text/html\n
<html>
<body>
   <p>%s</p>
</body>
</html>
""" % (message,)
```

I have played with adding and removing quotes on the full path in the shebang and that hasn't helped.

I have these in httpd.conf -

```
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so

<Directory "C:\Users\raj_d\webroot\tsp_quick\cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    # Options None
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I made sure that python was excutable from the shebang path -

```
C:\>C:\Users\raj_d\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

RD

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out.

First and foremost, one should always follow the guidelines :)

In my case, I gave up too quickly in running the script from command line. I had installed Python 3.8.3 from the Microsoft store and for some reason every time I ran the script from the command line, a new cmd window would popup and close very quickly. I was unable to change that behavior and couldn't see what was going wrong.

So I uninstalled python, downloaded the new installer from python's site, and installed in a common location where my dev tools are installed. Now, I could run my script from command line and was able to see what the actual problem was.

It turned out to be **print**! Here is the modified code which works just fine and the shebang became simpler as well.

```
#!C:\tools\python\\python.exe
import cgi, os
import cgitb
import time

cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
# Get filename here.
fileitem = form['filename']
# Test if the file was uploaded
if fileitem.filename:
   # strip leading path from file name to avoid
   # directory traversal attacks
   fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
   # open('/tmp/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())
   message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'
else:
   message = 'No file was uploaded'
a = """Content-Type: text/html\n
<html>
<body>
<p>{}</p>
</body>
</html>
"""
print (a.format(message))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues trying to execute *.py files in Apache on Windows. I followed the Apache CGI setup guide, but the problem (as you allude to) is with the Python executable in

```
C:/Users/../AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/Python/
```

For some reason that I can't figure out, Apache won't allow you to use the Python interpreter in this location. I did as you suggested and uninstalled Python 3.10.x and re-installed on my D: drive and hey presto, it just worked.
I suspect this is a windows-only quirk, probably a security issue.